# translations and 了

Tags: particles

I was practicing translating the following sentences:

Relax, this problem has already been solved!
放輕鬆吧，這個問題已經解決了。

That foreigner hasn’t taken a bus for a long time.
那個外國人很久沒有搭巴士了。

I feel I added 了 at the end of each sentence based on feel but am unsure why. If I omitted 了 would the sentences still be correct? What meaning is added by 了 in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation adding LE at the end means, "now" or "already".

> That foreigner hasn’t taken a bus for a long time, now.

What meaning does this "now" adds? Well, it adds a meaning of crossing some threshold in the mind of the utterer.

> Before now, his not taking a bus was alright, but now... well it's just not normal in some sence any more.